# C++ compiling winsock.h and thread on linux, travis

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, travis-ci

How to compile the .cpp file, which has such includes as `winsock.h` and `thread`, in Travis CI? Travis CI provides linux operating system.

There is no need to launch the program, it just should be compiled.

Comment: Please look at the preview in order to make sure your submission is readable. Use [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Compiling on travis isn't different from compiling on a normal linux box. What's your actual problem?